# Transformation better suited for very small numbers

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, exponential-function, transformation

`displacement = transform(output)`

Aim is to get the transformation function and suitable `output`.

So we have `displacement` range from $-0.05$ to $+0.05$. `displacement` can be as small as $10^{-12}$.

Properties of `output`

1. Small changes in `displacement` of the order of `10^-12` should have decent change in `output`

**expected**

```
displacement output
0.05          100.000
.
.
10^-12
0              0.000
-10^-12
.
.
.
-0.05         -100.000
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Either make the derivative large or make $y$'s asymptotic behaviour for small $x$ scale non-linearly, e.g. $y=Ax^{1/(2n+1)}$.

Comment: @J.G. Can you explain ```A``` and ```n```.

Comment: Well, for example, if you want $y(0)=0,\,y\left(\pm10^{-12}\right)=\pm0.05$ you could take $y=\sqrt[3]{\tfrac54}x^{1/9}$, unless I've miscalculated. But it all depends on _why_ you want $y$ to behave that way.

Comment: @J.G. I thiing you understood it other way round. I have added section in Question for your comments.

Comment: Based on @J.G. answer I got $x = ((\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{5})} y )^{9} $